# Sequelize findAndCountAll query selects fields that I haven't specified to select

Tags: group-by, sequelize.js

Here is the code I'm dealing with:

```
Transaction.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
      operation: 'NA_WITHDRAWAL',
      status: 'PENDING',
    },
    attributes: [
      [Sequelize.fn('sum', Sequelize.col('amount')), 'sum'],
      [Sequelize.fn('min', Sequelize.col('Transaction.createdAt')), 'oldestPendingWithdrawal'],
      'withdrawalNetwork',
      'Wallet->Coin.id',
      'Wallet->Coin.decimals',
      'Wallet->User.autoWithdrawal',
    ],
    group: ['withdrawalNetwork', 'Wallet->User.autoWithdrawal', 'Wallet->User.id', 'Wallet->Coin.decimals', 'Wallet->Coin.id'],
    include: [{
      model: Wallet,
      required: true,
      attributes: [],
      include: [{
        model: Coin,
        required: true,
        attributes: ['id', 'decimals'],
      }, {
        model: User,
        attributes: ['autoWithdrawal'],
        required: true,
      }],
    }],
  })
```

This query is indeed valid, however it forces me to include `Wallet->User.id` inside `group` array which does make my result wrong. It doesn't let me run without group by `Wallet->User.id` which makes sense as sequelize trying to select `Wallet->User.id` even me without specifying that I need to select user id in attributes section which is where I'm confused.

Below is the query generated by the above code (Note commented lines, which are unwanted - with those commented lines query runs fine and I get the needed output):

```
SELECT sum("amount") AS "sum", 
    min("Transaction"."createdAt") AS "oldestPendingWithdrawal", 
    "Transaction"."withdrawalNetwork", 
    "Wallet->Coin"."id", 
    "Wallet->Coin"."decimals", 
    "Wallet->User"."autoWithdrawal", 
    "Wallet->Coin"."id" AS "Wallet.Coin.id", 
    "Wallet->Coin"."decimals" AS "Wallet.Coin.decimals", 
    -- "Wallet->User"."id" AS "Wallet.User.id", 
"Wallet->User"."autoWithdrawal" AS "Wallet.User.autoWithdrawal" 
FROM "Transactions" AS "Transaction" 
INNER JOIN "Wallets" AS "Wallet" ON "Transaction"."WalletId" = "Wallet"."id" 
INNER JOIN "Coins" AS "Wallet->Coin" ON "Wallet"."CoinId" = "Wallet->Coin"."id" 
INNER JOIN "Users" AS "Wallet->User" ON "Wallet"."UserId" = "Wallet->User"."id" 
WHERE "Transaction"."operation" = 'NA_WITHDRAWAL' AND "Transaction"."status" = 'PENDING' 
GROUP BY 
    "withdrawalNetwork", 
    "Wallet->User"."autoWithdrawal", 
    "Wallet->Coin"."decimals", 
    -- "Wallet->User"."id",
    "Wallet->Coin"."id";
```

So I'm trying to write the code for the above query basically to exclude user id from selecting and grouping.

Really appreciate your contribution!

Comment: If the field you want to group is from the joined table or in the include clause, it won't work. It will always force you to add the Wallet and the -> with the column you are grouping. I hope the sequelise fixes this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize query with include to join tables, and grouping by a field from the included table will have limitations because Sequelize's built-in query builder doesn't directly support such SQL queries.

I recommend using a raw query for the same

```
 const result = await sequelize.query(
    'You're Find and Join Query and then grouping by',
    'GROUP BY <fieldName>', 
 );
```

This will be helpful for the nested includes and group by queries